# Filter array objects javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to filter an array of objects based on a specific condition. Specifically, I want to exclude the object with an ID equal to a given value and all objects that appear before the first object that doesn't satisfy this condition. How can I achieve this using a single loop?

Here's an example array:

```
const arr = [{ id: 10 }, { id: 20 }, { id: 30 }, { id: 40 }, { id: 50 }, { id: 60 }];
```

Let's say I have a target ID:

```
const myID = 25;
```

I want to filter the array to get the following result:

```
const result = [{ id: 20 }, { id: 30 }, { id: 40 }, { id: 50 }, { id: 60 }];
```

Comment: And also please do not tag-flood. It's not related to React or Angular at all

Answer (score -2):

```
const arr = [{ id: 10 }, { id: 20 }, { id: 30 }, { id: 40 }, { id: 50 }, { id: 60 }];
const myID = 25;

const index = arr.findIndex(obj => obj.id !== myID);
const result = index !== -1 ? arr.slice(index) : [];

console.log(result);
```